# Android WebviewActivity with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, webview, fragment

I have two problems really.

1. I am using a NavDrawer to show some items, and when the items are clicked, it opens another fragment. Everything works alright, except that I created a WebViewActivity separate and then use intent to show the URL on other fragment / activity. 
   When the item in the NavDrawer is clicked, it opens the corresponding URL, but the nav drawer icon at the top right isnt there for all WebViews... How do I make it show?
2. There is an item on the NavDrawer that opens a listView and items on the ListView opens a webview url. Problem is when the back key is pressed from the webview page, it goes back to the ListView, and when the back key is pressed again, it EXITs the application, I dont want this to happen, I want it to go to the first fragment, which is the HomeFragment.

I have tried the OnKeyDown, I kept getting errors, and it wants me to remove the override annotation.

Any user inputs / suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Post your code where you are commiting fragment transaction. ie, replacing one fragment with another. Also, Webview is in seperate activity right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

```
// Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```